# BookshelfJS: using a custom field name

Tags: bookshelf.js

We are wondering if it's possible to use a custom field name with bookshelf.js.

Let's say we have a field called: 'IDUser', but we want to use it in our code as user_id. Is there a way to map this in the model?

I've been searching for this but there isn't that much information.

Answer (score 1):

You can able to do with [Virtuals Plugin](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Virtuals)

```
var ModelWithVirtuals = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  virtuals: {
    user_id: function() {
        return this.get('IDUser');
    }
  }
});
```